# Как создать имена в цикле?

Tags: python, циклы, переменные

Мне нужно создать набор Y и проделать с ними некоторые действия, хочу делать через цикл, как я могу в цикле каждый раз Y обзывать с индексом? Т.е. мы создаем новую переменную в цикле и задаем ей некоторое имя. Т.e i = 0..5 и соответственно набор переменных y0, y1, y2, y3... y5

Comment: Это не нужно. Потому что ты не знаешь, как потом с этим работать. Делай список.

Comment: Для такого есть коллекции - списки и словари, например.